# Why is my WTForm HiddenField not being set to a default value?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I have an `EmployeeForm` with one of the fields comprising of a `PhotoForm` shown below:

```
class EmployeeForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Full Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    title = StringField('Job Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Company Email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    department = StringField('Department', validators=[DataRequired()])
    photo = FormField(PhotoForm)
```

Depending on whether a `USE_S3` config variable is set to `True` or `False` I want two fields on my photo object to be automatically set to default values like so:

```
class PhotoForm(Form):
    image = S3ImageUploadField(base_path=app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'],namegen=photo_name_generator)

    if app.config['USE_S3']:
        image_storage_type = HiddenField('s3')
        image_storage_bucket_name = HiddenField(app.config['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])
    else:
        image_storage_type = HiddenField('empty string')
        image_storage_bucket_name = HiddenField('empty string')
```

However, when I check the form's html there is no hidden field nor when I check the database on submission is there any set values on the `image_storage_type` and `image_bucket_name` and I can't figure it out why that is. I've checked on some stackoverflow questions but they don't exactly fit my question because I am using `Flask-Admin` and `WTForm` together which in my opinion makes it a little more trickier.

Also, my `admin.py` file for the form rendering looks like this:

```
class EmployeeView(ModelView):
     form = EmployeeForm
```

I'm not sure if this is a problem on WTForm's side or Flask-Admin's side but I've been trying for a long time to make this work. Does anyone has any ideas? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument for a field is its label. In your code you aren't passing data into the field, you are setting its label. Set the default data with the `default` kwarg.

```
from wtforms import Form, HiddenField

class PhotoForm(Form):
    default_image_data = "foo" if True else "bar"

    image_storage_type = HiddenField('image storage', default=default_image_data)

>>> form = PhotoForm()
>>> form.image_storage_type.data
'foo'
>>> form.image_storage_type()
u'<input id="image_storage_type" name="image_storage_type" type="hidden" value="foo">'
```

Comment: Thanks @jumbopap. I was about to pull my hair out.